# Search string with specific termination DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

Im trying to perform a search in DXL of a string that ends with specific characteres Im not able to find the way to perform this.

Example, I'm looking for 
" A: 23.1.23.2.4"
But if this contains at the end  the character "~"  the find function does not work

> Example Where the skip list contains "A: 12.2.1.4.5~ text text text text"
>   I just need to know in the object.text contains A: 12.2.1.4.5

```
string string_text = "A: 12.2.1.4.5"
if(find(skip[i],string_text,string_text)){
    modify_attributes(req_text)
    }else{
    output <<   "stgring not found : "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression, like this

```
void modify_attributes (string fulltext) {print "modifying.."}

string fulltext =  "A: 12.2.1.4.5~ text text text text"


Regexp searchme = regexp2 "A: 12.2.1.4.5"
if(searchme (fulltext)){
    modify_attributes(fulltext)
}else{
    print "string not found "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "find"-method for Skip lists is O(1), if I am not mistaken. But for that to work properly, the key, you are asking for, has to match exactly.
So, to benefit from the speed of value-retrieval by the find method, I suggest, that you have a look at your code part, where you put stuff into your Skip, (only put "clean" information in the Skip, which you know, you want to ask for later on).
That of course only works, if you have the possibility to do so, i.e. you don't get the Skip from somewhere you don't have control over..